# Configuring Oracle Wallet in JBOSS 6.4 EAP + spring + java application

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jboss, wallet

I am trying to configure a connection with oracle Wallet in a java application, JDK 1.8 over JBoss 6.4 eap, I follow the steps given in the following link https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-data-warehouse-cloud/user/connect-jdbc-thin-wallet.html#GUID-5ED3C08C-1A84-4E5A-B07A-A5114951AA9E, I configure the datasource with the corresponding url, I include libraries ojdb8.jar, ucp.jar, oraclepki.jar, osdt_core. jar, osdt_cert.jar and I have done everything indicated there. I start the application and when trying to connect the error is always the same:

```
    08:16:47,396 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.fillToMin:792] IJ000610: Unable to fill pool: javax.resource.ResourceException: Could not create connection
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:356)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:304)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:834) [ironjacamar-core-impl-1.0.31.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.31.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.fillToMin(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:775) [ironjacamar-core-impl-1.0.31.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.31.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.PoolFiller.run(PoolFiller.java:97) [ironjacamar-core-impl-1.0.31.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.31.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No se han encontrado las clases PKI. Para utilizar la funcionalidad de 'connect /', oraclepki.jar debe estar en classpath: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/security/pki/OracleWallet
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.getSecretStoreCredentials(PhysicalConnection.java:2979)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.parseUrl(PhysicalConnection.java:2745)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.readConnectionProperties(PhysicalConnection.java:2283)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:517)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:228)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:328)
    ... 5 more
```

I have tried to load oraclepki.jar (and the other dependencies) in different ways, from maven, from intellij including it in the classpath .... I don't know why it never finds these classes.

Comment that in Oracle sql developer I was able to connect to the Wallet without problems.

I would appreciate any hints or advice, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm what is the JDBC driver that you are trying to connect with? It is very important to know the JDK version and JDBC version. Check out this [page](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/java-connectivity-to-atp.html) for instructions. Also, are you connecting to Autonomous Transaction Processing?

https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/java-connectivity-to-atp.html

Comment: Hi, I am using ojdbc 18.3 to connect. And I'm trying to connect to Oracle Autonomous Data Warehouse

Comment: Can you make you if you have TNS_ADMIN pointing to the Oracle Wallets in the connection URL? Take a look at the videos and pre-requisites on this page (www.oracle.com/jdbc)